# How do you Insert a newid() into column while using FROM opensjon

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, datatables

I want to insert a `newid()` into a table.  It's not supplied in the JSON object itself, so I need to pass it in somehow.  I can't seem to do that...

```
declare @jsonString nvarchar(max),

--sample incoming data, JSON object
set @jsonString = '{

    "PosTitle": "Tech",
    "PosCode": "699887",
    "FileName": "clickme.exe",

}'
```

I can parse the JSON string successfully, and insert it into the temp table:

```
    --establish temp table
CREATE TABLE #tblDestination(
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] default newsequentialid(),
    [PosTitle] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [PosCode] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [FileName] [varchar](60) NULL,

)

--parse the JSON string
--and insert it into the temp table
insert into #tblDestination
select *
from openjson(@jsonString, '$')
with 
(

    newid(), --I need to insert a newid() into the [id column]
    PosTitle varchar(80) '$.PosTitle',
    PosCode varchar(5) '$.PosCode',
    [FileName] varchar(60) '$.FileName',


)
```

I kinda can get it to work...  Columns in the source must be lined up perfectly with the destination.  The source doesn't have a `newid()`, so I need to build one and pass it in... but I can't figure out how to do that.

My understanding is that `with` is part of a CTE.

I was trying to avoid having to declare a var for each of the keys/values, and manually plucking each one out via `select JSON_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OpenJson` is a table valued function, simply select `NewId()` and `*` from it.
Also, Always specify the columns list when inserting data into a table:

```
insert into #tblDestination ([id], [PosTitle], [PosCode], [FileName])
select newid(), *
from openjson(@jsonString, '$')
with 
(
    PosTitle varchar(80) '$.PosTitle',
    PosCode varchar(5) '$.PosCode',
    [FileName] varchar(60) '$.FileName'
)
```

Comment: Cool, thank you, this is perfect!  I didn't know I could manipulate the select statement at that particular spot.  Good to know I can manipulate more data if I need to.

Comment: Glad to help :-)